# How to make this generated terrain flat-shaded?

Tags: java, 3d, terrain-rendering, shading

I'm generating a relatively low-poly terrain for my game using the code below:

```
for (int z = 0; z < VERTEX_COUNT; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < VERTEX_COUNT; x++) {
        final float posX = x / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        final float height = generateHeight(x, z);
        final float posY = height;
        final float posZ = z / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
        final Vector3 nor = getNormals(x, z);
        final float norX = nor.x;
        final float norY = nor.y;
        final float norZ = nor.z;
        final float texU = x / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1);
        final float texV = z / ((float) VERTEX_COUNT - 1);

        // Create vertex
    }
}

for (int z = 0; z < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < VERTEX_COUNT - 1; x++) {
        final int topLeft = (z * VERTEX_COUNT) + x;
        final int topRight = topLeft + 1;
        final int bottomLeft = ((z + 1) * VERTEX_COUNT) + x;
        final int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;

        //Triangle 1: topLeft - bottomLeft - topRight
        //Triangle 2: topRight - bottomLeft - mottomRight
    }
}

private Vector3 getNormals(final int x, final int z) {
    final float heightL = generateHeight(x - 1, z);
    final float heightR = generateHeight(x + 1, z);
    final float heightD = generateHeight(x, z - 1);
    final float heightU = generateHeight(x, z + 1);
    return new Vector3(heightL - heightR, 2f, heightD - heightU).nor();
}
```

This works perfectly fine and generates a smooth terrain mesh. The problem is I want this mesh to use flat shading; i.e. I don't want vertices to be shared between triangles. But I don't know how I would duplicate the vertices and find the appropriate indices to properly index the mesh. Any help?

Here's in image from google in case it wasn't clear (left shading is what I want, right is what I have): [image: example]

---

P.S. I found this code for the Unity scripting language:

```
Vector3[] oldVerts = mesh.vertices;
int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[triangles.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++) {
    vertices[i] = oldVerts[triangles[i]];
    triangles[i] = i;
}
mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.triangles = triangles;
```

Perhaps this is the solution I'm looking for? If so, how can I translate this code to using `float[]` instead of `Vector3[]` array for my vertices? And what is the `triangles` array, the indices?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in 2 ways.

The first is very simple, and is how ThinMatrix did it in his game. When you pass the normal from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, apply the `flat` attribute to it:

```
flat in vec3 normal;
```

The second way is harder and uses more resources, but it's more flexible. You basically have to insert every triangle separately. Your VBO should look something like this:

```
0, 0.5, 0,  // pos1  }
0, 0.6, 1,  // pos2  }  first triangle
1, 0.7, 0,  // pos3  }

1, 0.7, 0,  // pos 4 }
0, 0.6, 1,  // pos 5 }  second triangle
1, 0.7, 1   // pos 6 }
```

You don't need an index buffer if you do this, you can use `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: What does the `flat` qualifier do? Disable interpolation? And what GLSL version do I need to use `flat`?

Comment: I tried using the flat qualifier, but it doesn't seem to have worked. I used it like this `flat varying vec3 v_normal;` in my fragment shader. When it didn't work I also tried applying it in my vertex shader like this `flat varying vec3 v_normal;` with no results. Also, it seems like I have to write `#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : require` for flat to work in the first place. What's up with that?

Comment: @Charanor 1.) the varying qualifier is deprecated, use `in` and `out` 2.) You have to put it before both  the in and out statement and you need to have at least glsl version 150.

Comment: I was just going to post an update when you commented! I changed the version to 330 and it still doesn't work. Also changed `varying` to `in` or `out` as well with no result.

Comment: @Charanor If you're sure you have `flat out vec3 v_normal` and `flat in vec3 v_normal` in the vertex and fragment shader in this order, than there's probably a compatibility issue somewhere, try checking which version of glsl your GPU supports.

Comment: My supported GL version is `4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.69` and GLSL version is `4.50 NVIDIA`.

Comment: @Charanor Did you specify the shader version, when you put the flat before both attributes?

Comment: Yes, `#version 330`. Looking at resources I find online they seem to be doing exactly what I'm doing. I'm stumped